# How to integrate Stripe checkout to android?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

How to integrate Stripe checkout to android?
I know how to do it in Ios but the android implementation sounds complicated
I already read
https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android
and 
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android

I dont wanna use android pay with stripe..other option i have is creating a custom payment form....which is not that easy.
In Ios you can do this by few line of codes. This is how it done in Ios.
I'm wondering if there is similar easy to use code for android.Thanks

```
func stripePayment() {
    PaymentType = "2"
    let options = STPCheckoutOptions()
    options.publishableKey = stripePublishableKey
    if (appleMerchantId != "") {
        options.appleMerchantId = appleMerchantId
    }
    options.companyName = "Create Delivery"
    options.purchaseDescription = "CreateDelivery"
  //  options.purchaseCurrency = "USD"
    options.purchaseAmount = UInt(createDeliveryPrice)
    println(options.purchaseAmount)
    options.logoColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 183.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let presenter = STPPaymentPresenter(checkoutOptions: options, delegate: self)
    presenter.requestPaymentFromPresentingViewController(self)

}

func paymentPresenter(presenter: STPPaymentPresenter!, didCreateStripeToken token: STPToken!, completion: STPTokenSubmissionHandler!) {
    createBackendChargeWithToken(token, completion: completion)
}

func paymentPresenter(presenter: STPPaymentPresenter!, didFinishWithStatus status: STPPaymentStatus, error: NSError!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        switch(status) {
        case .UserCancelled:
            return // just do nothing in this case
        case .Success:
            self.UploadData()
            println("great success!")
        case .Error:
            println("oh no, an error 111:")
        }
    })
}

// This is optional, and used to customize the line items shown on the Apple Pay sheet.
func paymentPresenter(presenter: STPPaymentPresenter!, didPreparePaymentRequest request: PKPaymentRequest!) -> PKPaymentRequest! {
    request.paymentSummaryItems = [
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Create Delivery", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: DeliveryPriceText)),
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "shipping", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.00"))
    ]
    return request
}
```

Comment: There is no similar feature at the moment for Android. You need to build your own form instead AFAIK.

Comment: Its also been deprecated in iOS